# How to fix context cannot be declared Issue with configuring CookiePolicyOptions in startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-authorization

I'm trying to configure Startup.cs file to comform with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2 but I'm getting error in `options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;` The error is as follows: "A local parameter named 'context' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"

Below is my Sturtup.cs fragment

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });   ...
```

Does anybody encountered this issue? I was looking for solving to this, but without success. Every hint will be very helpful.

Comment: try changing 'context' to another name

Comment: Wow that works. Can you explain why I can't use "context"?
Thank you very much for help!

Comment: you already had the answer in the question ''context' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope', this name is protected local variable, it is used for some reason by .net, so you can't put the same name as the local variable

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim Thank you very much once again for clarification!

Comment: glad to help ! :D